# Need Help in pattern matching selenium IDE

Tags: pattern-matching, selenium-ide

I have two variables oriname and username

oriname consists of a series of long name like jack marco ferdinand
username is just jack

How do I write the pattern in my seleium IDE to match oriname and username ?
(if true then proceed)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>jack marco ferdinand</td>
    <td>oriname</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>jack</td>
    <td>username</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['oriname'].indexOf(storedVars['username']) &gt; -1</td>
    <td>true</td>
</tr>
```